# Twilio client sdk for ios error code 31002

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I have a Twilio app that is based on SwiftTwilioClientQuickstart. This is the old Client SDK, not Voice SDK. The app builds and runs. When I attempt to dial, it gives me an error "Twilio Services Error".

> Error Domain=TwilioServicesErrorDomain Code=31002 "Twilio Services Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Twilio Services Error}

What is error code 31002?

Code

```
func initializeTwilioDevice(_ token:String) {
    // confirmed this function is called 
    print("initializeTwilioDevice with token \(token)")
    device = TCDevice.init(capabilityToken: token, delegate: self)   
}
//MARK: TCDeviceDelegate
func deviceDidStartListening(forIncomingConnections device: TCDevice) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Started listening for incoming connections"
    }

}

func device(_ device: TCDevice, didStopListeningForIncomingConnections error: Error?) {
    print("func device didStopListeningForIncomingConnections")

    if let error = error {
        print("func device " + error.localizedDescription)
        print(error)
    }
}

func device(_ device: TCDevice, didReceiveIncomingConnection connection: TCConnection) {
    print("func device didReceiveIncomingConnection")
    if let parameters = connection.parameters {
        let from = parameters["From"]
        let message = "Incoming call from \(from)"
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Incoming Call", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            connection.delegate = self
            connection.accept()
            self.connection = connection
        })
        let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            connection.reject()
        })
        alertController.addAction(acceptAction)
        alertController.addAction(declineAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func device(_ device: TCDevice, didReceivePresenceUpdate presenceEvent: TCPresenceEvent) {
    print("func device didReceivePresenceUpdate")
}



//MARK: TCConnectionDelegate
func connectionDidConnect(_ connection: TCConnection) {
    statusLabel.text = "Connected"
    hangUpButton.isEnabled = true
}

func connectionDidDisconnect(_ connection: TCConnection) {
    print("disconnect")
    statusLabel.text = "Disconnected"
    dialButton.isEnabled = true
    hangUpButton.isEnabled = false
}

func connectionDidStartConnecting(_ connection: TCConnection) {
    statusLabel.text = "Started connecting...."
}

func connection(_ connection: TCConnection, didFailWithError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("func connection:" + error.localizedDescription)
        print(error)
    }
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    dial(dialTextField)
    dialTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

//MARK: IB Actions
@IBAction func hangUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let connection = connection {
        connection.disconnect()
    }
}

@IBAction func dial(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let device = device {
        print("dial \(dialTextField.text!)")
        connection = device.connect(["To":dialTextField.text!], delegate: self)
        dialButton.isEnabled = false
        dialTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error Domain=TwilioServicesErrorDomain Code=31002 "Twilio Services Error" UserInfo=

The error says, **Twilio** is refusing your connection. The most likely cause of something like this is that **you aren't sending the correct token** for your app.

you can get the more information related to the Error code in [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors)

Comment: Turns out you were right.  I carefully went through all the IDs and found that one of them was incorrect.

Comment: I switched to using my production Twilio credentials, and I got a little bit further (I heard a message "An application error has occurred. Goodbye."), but it still then disconnected the call with `Error: Connection Declined`.